# Excel - create a lookup with multiple values and return Y/N/Underdetermined

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to lookup data in a table that has multiple instances of the lookup value and want to return a value from another column that is then turned into the value of that 2nd column or 'unknown' if there are multiple values for the same lookup value.

Data:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have Office 365, you can use:

```
E2: =LET(x,UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$13,$A$2:$A$13=D2)),
         IF(COUNTA(x)=1, x,"unknown"))
```

[image]

- `FILTER` returns all the Column 2 values that correspond to the designated Column 1 value
- `UNIQUE` returns only the different items in that filtered list

  - If they all match, `UNIQUE` will only return a single item
  - Test that there is a single item with `COUNTA`

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

> =IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12=D2)*($B$2:$B$12="Y"))>0,SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12=D2)*($B$2:$B$12="N"))=0),"Y",IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12=D2)*($B$2:$B$12="Y"))=0,SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12=D2)*($B$2:$B$12="N"))>0),"N",IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12=D2)*($B$2:$B$12="Y"))>0,SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12=D2)*($B$2:$B$12="N"))>0),"Unknown","")))

[image]

Comment: I am getting errors when I use the formula above for the larger data set but I like the idea of using SUMPRODUCT. Ill see if I figure them out

Answer (score 0):

Just count how many times the value appears and use that to decide what to do. For example:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A$1000,$D2)>1,"Unknown",IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D2,$A$2:$B$1000,2,FALSE),"Not found"))
```

If more than one, the answer is ambiguous, if 1 then the VLOOKUP returns a value, if 0, VLOOKUP fails and the IFERROR catches it.